# Force Jquery-UI Datepicker to open under the Input?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I´m using a Datepicker with Jquery-Ui and I need it to always display under the input.

I checked the API documentation, googled it and searched for it on Stackoverflow, but I could not find a solution: I tried these codes:

```
popup: {
    position: "bottom left",
    origin: "top left"
},
```

__

```
orientation: "bottom",
```

Anyone has an idea how to do this?

Comment: jQury UI DatePicker does not have `popup` option. So I'm a little confused. it does have a `showOptions` option. I think this will help: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showOptions

Comment: You can also make use of `.position()`. This may be a bit hard to do, but it can be done.

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces problem. By default a jQueryUI datepicker already opens under the input. Sounds like you are using a different plugin or have a css conflict

Comment: Here is a [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/ypPobJ?editors=1111) where the issue is reproduced.

Comment: @Twisty I tried the showOptions with "down", did not work too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can do this with an inline datepicker.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/0e3njzoe/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="tall">
  Tall Div
</div>
<label for="myDate">Date</label>
<input type="text" id="myDate" />
<div id="myDatePicker"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#myDatePicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date) {
      $("#myDate").val(date);
      $("#myDatePicker").hide();
    }
  }).position({
    my: "left top",
    at: "left bottom",
    of: $("#myDate"),
    collision: "none"
  }).hide();
  $("#myDate").focus(function() {
    $("#myDatePicker").show();
  })
});
```

You can place the datepicker largely anyplace and then use `.position()` to place it under the input field. It will, by default, try to flip if it detects collision. You can turn this off. See more: http://api.jqueryui.com/position/

It's a little extra work to manage, but it give you the control you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative Answer to [Twistys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463319/twisty) Answer.**

The Jquery UI Datepicker displays the calendar under the input by default, if it doesn´t, mostly it has simply no space under the input, as it was in my case.

**So just change the size of the Datepicker and it will display under the input.**

```
<style>.ui-datepicker {font-size:70%; }</style>
```

Comment: You did not clarify in your OP that you had space "under" the input. You stated "*I need it to always display under the input*". Your answer will work on one specific screen size. Datepicker still uses collision detection and if the screen is small enough, it will flip it.

Comment: I did not clarify it because I did not know that the problem was about the space. Your right, that´s why I checked your answer but I added another answer so other people check their space before changing their code.