# get date picker under the text field

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I want get my date pickers below my date text fields. instead of that it appears top of them.how can I customize the position.

```
    <div class="form" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
        <label for="status-select" class="mr-2">From Date</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker-from-date" name="datepicker-from-date" value="<?php  if (isset($FROM_DATE) && !is_null($FROM_DATE)){ echo $FROM_DATE;  } ?>" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" >
    </div>
    
   <script>
        $("#datepicker-from-date").datepicker();
   </script>
```

[here is the screenshot of my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvWqO.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130201/force-jquery-ui-datepicker-to-open-under-the-input

Comment: what is your jquery version you are currently running?

Answer (score 0):

I think You can use this

```html
<input type="date" name="datepicker">
```